# DaVinci resolve 16 is not opening on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: installed-programs

I have installed Davici resolve 16 software, but when I try to run DaVinci running the binary file with command `./resolve`, then the program is not opening.

This is the output on my terminal:

```
ActCCMessage Already in Table: Code= c005, Mode= 13, Level=  1, CmdKey= -1, Option= 0
ActCCMessage Already in Table: Code= c006, Mode= 13, Level=  1, CmdKey= -1, Option= 0
ActCCMessage Already in Table: Code= c007, Mode= 13, Level=  1, CmdKey= -1, Option= 0
ActCCMessage Already in Table: Code= 2282, Mode=  0, Level=  0, CmdKey= 8, Option= 0
PnlMsgActionStringAdapter Already in Table: Code= 615e, Mode=  0, Level=  0, CmdKey= -1, Option= 0
16.1.1 (#005) Linux/Clang
Main thread starts: 1F869C40
[0x7f431f869c40] | Undefined            | INFO  | 2019-11-22 18:03:17,514 | --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[0x7f431f869c40] | Undefined            | INFO  | 2019-11-22 18:03:17,515 | Loaded log config from /home/dario/.local/share/DaVinciResolve/configs/log-conf.xml
[0x7f431f869c40] | Undefined            | INFO  | 2019-11-22 18:03:17,515 | --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
JACK Audio Connection Kit
PulseAudio Sound Server
HDA Intel PCH, Generic AnalogDefault Audio Device
HDA Intel PCH, Generic AnalogFront speakers
HDA Intel PCH, Generic Analog2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
HDA Intel PCH, Generic Analog4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
HDA Intel PCH, Generic Analog4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
HDA Intel PCH, Generic Analog5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
HDA Intel PCH, Generic Analog5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
HDA Intel PCH, Generic Analog7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 0HDMI Audio Output
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 1HDMI Audio Output
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 2HDMI Audio Output
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 3HDMI Audio Output
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 4HDMI Audio Output
HDA Intel PCH, Generic AnalogDirect sample mixing device
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 0Direct sample mixing device
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 1Direct sample mixing device
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 2Direct sample mixing device
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 3Direct sample mixing device
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 4Direct sample mixing device
HDA Intel PCH, Generic AnalogDirect sample snooping device
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 0Direct sample snooping device
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 1Direct sample snooping device
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 2Direct sample snooping device
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 3Direct sample snooping device
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 4Direct sample snooping device
HDA Intel PCH, Generic AnalogDirect hardware device without any conversions
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 0Direct hardware device without any conversions
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 1Direct hardware device without any conversions
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 2Direct hardware device without any conversions
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 3Direct hardware device without any conversions
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 4Direct hardware device without any conversions
HDA Intel PCH, Generic AnalogHardware device with all software conversions
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 0Hardware device with all software conversions
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 1Hardware device with all software conversions
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 2Hardware device with all software conversions
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 3Hardware device with all software conversions
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 4Hardware device with all software conversions
HDA Intel PCHUSB Stream Output
Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
JACK Audio Connection Kit
PulseAudio Sound Server
HDA Intel PCH, Generic AnalogDefault Audio Device
HDA Intel PCH, Generic AnalogFront speakers
HDA Intel PCH, Generic Analog2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
HDA Intel PCH, Generic Analog4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
HDA Intel PCH, Generic Analog4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
HDA Intel PCH, Generic Analog5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
HDA Intel PCH, Generic Analog5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
HDA Intel PCH, Generic Analog7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 0HDMI Audio Output
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 1HDMI Audio Output
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 2HDMI Audio Output
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 3HDMI Audio Output
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 4HDMI Audio Output
HDA Intel PCH, Generic AnalogDirect sample mixing device
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 0Direct sample mixing device
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 1Direct sample mixing device
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 2Direct sample mixing device
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 3Direct sample mixing device
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 4Direct sample mixing device
HDA Intel PCH, Generic AnalogDirect sample snooping device
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 0Direct sample snooping device
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 1Direct sample snooping device
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 2Direct sample snooping device
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 3Direct sample snooping device
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 4Direct sample snooping device
HDA Intel PCH, Generic AnalogDirect hardware device without any conversions
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 0Direct hardware device without any conversions
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 1Direct hardware device without any conversions
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 2Direct hardware device without any conversions
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 3Direct hardware device without any conversions
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 4Direct hardware device without any conversions
HDA Intel PCH, Generic AnalogHardware device with all software conversions
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 0Hardware device with all software conversions
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 1Hardware device with all software conversions
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 2Hardware device with all software conversions
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 3Hardware device with all software conversions
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 4Hardware device with all software conversions
HDA Intel PCHUSB Stream Output
Playback/recording through the PulseAudio sound server
Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
JACK Audio Connection Kit
PulseAudio Sound Server
HDA Intel PCH, Generic AnalogDefault Audio Device
HDA Intel PCH, Generic AnalogFront speakers
HDA Intel PCH, Generic Analog2.1 Surround output to Front and Subwoofer speakers
HDA Intel PCH, Generic Analog4.0 Surround output to Front and Rear speakers
HDA Intel PCH, Generic Analog4.1 Surround output to Front, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
HDA Intel PCH, Generic Analog5.0 Surround output to Front, Center and Rear speakers
HDA Intel PCH, Generic Analog5.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Rear and Subwoofer speakers
HDA Intel PCH, Generic Analog7.1 Surround output to Front, Center, Side, Rear and Woofer speakers
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 0HDMI Audio Output
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 1HDMI Audio Output
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 2HDMI Audio Output
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 3HDMI Audio Output
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 4HDMI Audio Output
HDA Intel PCH, Generic AnalogDirect sample mixing device
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 0Direct sample mixing device
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 1Direct sample mixing device
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 2Direct sample mixing device
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 3Direct sample mixing device
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 4Direct sample mixing device
HDA Intel PCH, Generic AnalogDirect sample snooping device
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 0Direct sample snooping device
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 1Direct sample snooping device
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 2Direct sample snooping device
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 3Direct sample snooping device
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 4Direct sample snooping device
HDA Intel PCH, Generic AnalogDirect hardware device without any conversions
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 0Direct hardware device without any conversions
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 1Direct hardware device without any conversions
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 2Direct hardware device without any conversions
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 3Direct hardware device without any conversions
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 4Direct hardware device without any conversions
HDA Intel PCH, Generic AnalogHardware device with all software conversions
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 0Hardware device with all software conversions
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 1Hardware device with all software conversions
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 2Hardware device with all software conversions
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 3Hardware device with all software conversions
HDA Intel PCH, HDMI 4Hardware device with all software conversions
HDA Intel PCHUSB Stream Output
```

Any suggestions?

Solution: the GPU of my computer unfortunatly was not compatible.